# What is the name of this biting bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I just was bitten by a bug!!! It is 3mm long and has large pincers. Here is a photo:
[image]
I live in Colorado. Any help identifying it would be great.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a larva of a green lacewing (Family Chrysopidae). Yes, they can bite hard but you're not its intended victim and they're not only harmless but beneficial as they're aggressive predators of aphids and other soft bodied plant pests. I can't be specific to what species of lacewing as they look fairly similar.

Another larva that looks very similar to yours.

[image]
[Source](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1183624/bgimage) from BugGuide.net

What the adult looks like (remember,they're an entire insect family so there are differences but not to most people).

[image]
[Source](http://bugguide.net/node/view/965757/bgpage) also from BugGuide.net

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick identification. Glad I caught it and released it ;)

Comment: That's rather interesting. The larva itself seems terribly threatening, while the lacewing looks cute!

Answer (score 21):

That's a larva of an insect from the [Order Neuroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera), probably from the Family Chrysopidae. Their common name in English is [green lacewings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopidae).

Here is a larva very similar to your specimen:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://www.cedarcreek.umn.edu/insects/newslides/023neurop2line.jpg</sup>

Here is another one, also from the Family Chrysopidae (the colour pattern is not quite the same, but you can see the resemblance):

[image]

<sup>Source: http://bugguide.net/node/view/803060</sup>

And here is the imago (adult), for comparison:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera#/media/File:Crisopid_July_2013-9a.jpg</sup>

Comment: When I gathered my links to post an answer, there wasn't one yet. But you obviously beat me to it!

Comment: Doing it on my phone with quick breaks to look after lemon muffins I was making. Multi-tasking. :)

Comment: Have to use phone (tablet charge was low & computer sadly has a glitch & can't be accessed till fixed). Using SE app but still frustrating.

Comment: No, Geraldo, I think you might've misunderstood me. I wasn't *trying* to be the first. At the time I saw the question, no one had answered. I knew what it was but also knew I couldn't simply give an answer without references. There are other times species ID is a puzzle to me so I see if I can figure it out as a challenge to myself but don't bother answering since I'm sure someone will later. It's not a contest for me. I'm not that sort of person. I'm not at all competitive. Did you think I was trying to be first? If so, I apologise. My comment about you beating me was made light-heartedly.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the app shows the "1 new answer to this question" in real time like the site does. I'd assume innocence (especially since @Jude insists that was the case).

Comment: Maxathousand, that information makes all the difference. I didn't know that because, on the mobile, I use a browser (which, by the way, also don't show "1 new answer" in real time). It's explained now. @Jude, let's clean this up, I'm deleting all the comments.

Comment: Thanks for understanding, maxathousand. There wasn't any answer. That's why I answered. When someone's already answered, I don't add an answer - it's redundant - which is why I didn't understand Geraldo. Good idea to have these comments deleted **and** I'm going to delete my SE app too.